# Deploy docker servce to swarm with traefik 2.0

Tags: docker, deployment, traefik, swarm

I have a docker swarm with a network 
network name: traefik-net 
type: overlay
scope: swarm

Then i have a docker compose that works.

```
services:
  angularDocs:
    image: artifactory.company.com/containers/angular-docs:branchName
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.angularDocs.rule=Host(`branchName.angular.swarm.company.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.angularDocs.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
´´´

But instead of creating a compose file for each container image. I would like to do 
docker service create --options artifactory.company.com/containers/angular-docs:branchName
```

but when i try like this, it does not work with traefik

```
docker service create --name angulardocs  --label "traefik.http.routers.angulardocs.rule=Host(`branchName.angular.swarm.company.com`)" --label "traefik.http.services.angulardocs.loadbalancer.server.port=80" --network traefik-net artifactory.company.com/containers/angular-docs:branchName
```

In traefik 2.0 i get a route

Host(`angulardocs-1-egyumq4nfke1lz3ohya38mwsj`)

instead of Host(`v8.angular.company.com`)

It is like the the labels are configured wrong compared to when labels are in the compose file.

I hope somebody has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you lost a "entrypoints". like below:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.angularDocs.entrypoints=http # I don't know your entrypoints name
```